# Is the exponential map of complex spin group surjective?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

The complex spin group $Spin(n,C)$ is defined as the double cover of $SO(n,C)$.

If the the exponential map is surjective, it will give a parametrization of this Lie group. Is it true for this non-compact Lie group?

The answer is NO. See the comments for details.

I want to add one more question:

Is $SO(n,C)$ weakly exponential, i.e. is the image of the exponential map dense in $SO(n,C)$?

e.g., $SO(2,C)≅C^\times$(the punctured plane), $SO(3,C)≅PSL(2,C)$, the exponential maps of which are surjective. But for $n\geq4$ the exponential maps are not surjective.

I think the answer is useful for numerical calculations.

Comment: your group is patently compact.

Comment: ... which implies that the exponential map is indeed surjective.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this mistake... I have corrected my question...

Comment: As a layman, I want to add two useful references on this topic. https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jmsj/1240433449 http://www.emis.de/journals/JLT/vol.15_no.1/wuestla2e.pdf

Comment: I add one more reference on this new question, which is very difficult for me. I hope this will help. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/248407470_Weakly_Exponential_Lie_Groups

Comment: The image of the exponential map contains the subset of regular elements (i.e. those with diagonalizable matrices), which is dense.